# No route matches [POST] "/profile_settings"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, controller, routes

I have the following form who should update the user, but i keep getting this No route matches [POST] "/profile_settings" message, and everything seems right so i don't know why

```
= form_for update_user_profile_setting_path(current_user.id), method: :post do |f|
    .profile_form
      %br
        = f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name',class: 'default-input text_field'
      %br
        = f.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email', class: 'default-input text_field', id: 'email_profile'
      %br
        = f.text_field :address, placeholder: 'Address', class: 'default-input text_field'
      %br
        = f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password', class: 'default-input text_field black-font'
      %br
        = f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: 'Password Confirmation', class: 'default-input text_field black-font'
      %br
        = f.file_field :avatar, placeholder: 'Avatar', class: 'default-input'
      .actions 
        = f.submit "Update Settings", class: 'btn btn-success default-input'
```

the controller method

```
def update_user
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(user_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

routes

```
resources :profile_settings, :only => [:index] do
  post :update_user, on: :member
end
```

I might be missing something, but i really don't know what...
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

After submitting, your form will look for an `update` method.

To respect the `CRUD` conventions, rename your `update_user` by `update`. Then, in your `routes`, replace the code you have with `resources :profile_settings, :only => [:index, :update]` or `resources :profile_settings`.

Comment: Thanks for the attention, Omar. Did it all i get the same error, but now my the method is shown as `patch` and another one with `put`

Answer (score 0):

Your form needs to be on the following route

```
/profile_settings/:user_id/edit
```

Also set the form tag to `= form_for(@user) do |f|`

Then it should automagically use the `update` controller method.

Answer (score 0):

`Update` takes either `Patch` or `Put`. You need to change the `routes` and `form`.

```
resources :profile_settings, :only => [:index] do
  patch :update_user, on: :member
end
```

And change

```
= form_for update_user_profile_setting_path(current_user.id), method: :post do
```

to

```
= form_for update_user_profile_setting_path(current_user.id), method: :patch do
```